# Scripting user enrollment on Microsoft AD CS

Tags: templates, certificate, pki, certreq

I need to be able to auto-enroll a huge number of users using Microsoft AD CS.
I have create a certificate template that these users are able to auto-enroll with.

I now need to create the requests and accept the certificates automatically, without UI interaction.

My first thought was to use **certreq** with -q option to suppress interaction:

```
certreq -enroll -user -q -PolicyServer "ldap://" "TemplateName"
```

The server then answers :

```
The request subject name is invalid or too long (0x80094001)
```

I think that the -q option enabled the use of default values, some of which might be empty.

**Is there any way to provide certreq for additional information (e.g. CN, SAN DNS...) while using an AD CS certificate template in command-line enroll?**

Comment: Oh, and if there's any way to create a .inf file for certreq -New from an AD CS Certificate Template, let me know !